# I want to create plesk subdomain via php script in my Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I want to create plesk subdomain via php script in my Laravel application. I am using the `laravelcollective/remote` package. After running:

```
$this->ssh->run('plesk bin subdomain ...')
```

It creates subdomain, but doesnt continue to other commands execution so I get nginx "`502 bad gateway`" error. I have checked logs, nginx gives just upstream prematurely closed, in my `plesk` admin logs I find out:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory './example.com/logs': File exists
ERROR: Cannot relink logs. Target directory '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/logs' is in invalid state.
```

Comment: What other commands do you want to run? Should the other commands be grouped into a Task? https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/ssh#tasks

Comment: No they are not groupped into a Task, I have run commands sepperatly, but I have commands that are groupped. To be clear I want to create subdomain and install project there. For example after creating subdomain next step is clone there the project, so in this phase I run groupped commands (clone, composer install etc.), but create subdomain command is single. Also I want to mentioned that this works when I run in command line, I mean I have wrote artisan command which do all commands and create subdomain too. Thanks